# How to debug and develop Azure DevOps extension without deployment?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I want to develop a simple Azure DevOps extension which displays some data in the table. My extension is based on [extension sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample).

Can I debug this extension outside Azure DevOps without the complete deployment process described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops)? As a complete newbie to Azure DevOps I cannot imagine my development cycle when I should deploy every single change. Or can be deployment automated somehow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [Azure DevOps Extension Hot Reload and Debug](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-hot-reload-and-debug).

Download and install the following tools:

- Visual Studio Code
- Firefox (because the VS Code Debugger for Chrome extension doesn't support iframes yet)
- The Debugger for Firefox VS Code extension
- The tfx-cli npm package
- The webpack npm package
- The webpack-dev-server npm package

In the above GitHub repo, you can find the full tutorial of how to debug the extension without deploying it. another tutorial also available [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/streamlining-azure-devops-extension-development/).