# How do I troubleshoot extensions in Azure DevOps Server that times out?

Tags: azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019

I have a couple of extensions installed on my Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1 patch 7.
The thing is, that all of them keeps failing on an regular basis.

But I have no idea where to look for trouble shooting...

I've tried reinstalling some, but they still doesn't work.
Then, a while later. They are ok again :/

I thought installing patch 7 would help, but the issue came back shortly after...

Comment: If you are the extension's author, please refer to this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58998619/how-to-debug-and-develop-azure-devops-extension-without-deployment) to debug your extension. If they are the 3rd-party extensions, please contact the extension’s author to report this issue and get professional help.
BTW, please check if you set proxy or firewall, which might cause this issue. If so, please review this doc: [Allowed address lists and network connections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops-2020) for guidance.

Comment: What about when *all* extensions fail periodically at the same time, and then automatically recovers several hours later again?

But what is the proxy issue? The AzDOS server is locked in behind a FW with no internet access...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems that this issue can be caused by Network proxy/firewall. You could contact the IT department to add certain IP addresses and domain URLs to the Allow list by following this doc: [Allowed address lists and network connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops-2020). Also capturing the Network logs to allow particular communications between extensions and your Azure DevOps server.

Comment: BTW, you could monitor [Azure DevOps Status history page](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history), to know the latest service report, which might cause this service interruption.

Comment: The status page is only for Az DevOps Services right?
There is no such feature of the on-prem version?

Comment: The status page is mainly for Azure DevOps Service. And some service events will affect core-service and then will affect both Azure DevOps Service and Azure DevOps Server. Also you could monitor this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020?view=azure-devops-2020 to learn latest Azure DevOps Server Release Notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure DevOps Server 2019 is soon to be a legacy product and I've now upgraded to Azure DevOps Server 2022.

So far, I haven't been able to replicate this issue.