# Azure devops extension fails on runs

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

I am developing an extension of azuredevops. I can build it, publish it, install it in my test organization and I can see it working.

When I try to use it stays waiting forever and I can see this error in the browser console

“Refused to connect to ‘https://browser.events.data.microsoft.com/OneCollector/1.0/?cors=true&content-type=application/x-json-stream&w=0’ because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: “connect-src .visualstudio.com wss://.visualstudio.com https://web.vortex.data.microsoft.com .dev.azure.com dev.azure.com wss://.dev.azure.com wss://dev.azure.com *.vsassets.io ms.gallery.vsassets.io vsassetscdn.azure.cn ms.gallerycdn.vsassets.io ms.gallerycdn.azure.cn *.blob.core.windows.net https://login.microsoftonline.com”.”

I've tried it with Edge and Chrome and the result is the same

I have built exactly this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-hub?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops

And I got the same error, so I assume I have some permissions problem but I can’t find the solution in the tutorials

Has anyone had that same problem or can you help me solve it? Thank you!

You should load the extension and see an example page (Hello world!) but it failed to run.  What am I missing?

Comment: I have these "wait forever" problems when I forget to call SDK.Init () at the entry point of the plugin.  But without debugger is hard to say. 
Try this extension that allows you debug and reload https://stackoverflow.com/a/59015656/245460

Comment: Thanks @KarelKral , i try this and send feedback